# ansible assign shell results specific hosts in hostvars using with_items

Tags: ansible

Basically i want modify an existing hostvars.
I have a dynamically generated array of hosts named "flash_hosts"

```
flash_hosts = ['host1', 'host2']
```

and a shell script which looks up a value for each host.
In following non-working code i try to assign each host the specific result of the script

```
- name:  Assign values to to host var
  shell:      "get-assigned-value.sh {{ item }}"
  register:   "{{ hostvars[item].mac=stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ flash_hosts }}"
```

How can i make this work in in ansible?  Basically i understand that register will not allow me to assign the value to hostvars directly, but how can this be solved then, as i need to iterate over the hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_fact` to debug your `register` results on host wise..

```
  - name: Assign values to to host var
    shell: "/path/to/get-assigned-value.sh {{ item }}"
    register: fileout
    with_items:
         - host1
         - host2

  - set_fact:
       firstHost: "{{ fileout.results[0] }}"
       secondHost: "{{ fileout.results[1] }}"

  - debug:
      var: firstHost.stdout

  - debug:
      var: secondHost.stdout
```

in the above example, `firstHost` is whole result of shell script running on first host, and `firstHost.stdout` gives the output of corresponding host shell script result.

Comment: yes, this comes closer, but now (for convenience and later use), how do we bring the results into the hostvars for each host (hostvars[item]) - I do not like keep global variable around when the results should be actually part each host

Answer (score 0):

It's possible *set_facts* and *delegate_to* the `flash_hosts` with [*delegate_facts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts).

But, to create a variable in `hostvars` the host must be declared in the inventory(static or dynamic). It's not necessary the host is accessible. For example

```
$ cat hosts
host1
host2
```

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    flash_hosts: ['host1', 'host2']
  tasks:
    - name:  Assign values to to host var
      command: "{{ playbook_dir }}/get-assigned-value.sh {{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ flash_hosts }}"
    - set_fact:
        mac: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item.item }}"
      delegate_facts: true
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[item].mac }}"
      loop: "{{ flash_hosts }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1) => 
  msg: mac address of host1
ok: [localhost] => (item=host2) => 
  msg: mac address of host2
```

with the script

```
$ cat get-assigned-value.sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in

    host1)
    printf "mac address of host1"
    ;;

    host2)
    printf "mac address of host2"
    ;;

    *)
    printf "unknown host"
    exit 1
    ;;

esac

exit 0
```

Comment: I see, so I think my description is incomplete, the hosts are not running (they need be flashed on a virtual host).  Therefore this solution would be working if the machines would active -

Comment: There are no `hostvars` for hosts not present in the inventory.